# What are the necessary conditions on the energy of the Euler-Lagrange equation to have an oscillating solution?

Tags: energy, lagrangian-formalism, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

Which condition(s) should the energy satisfy, such that the solution of the corresponding Euler-Lagrange equation is oscillating?

Comment: Can you please explain what Euler-Lagrange equation you are considering?

Comment: I do not have a special Euler-Lagrange equation in mind (so not only harmonic oscillation). I am searching for a general consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-linear systems of odinary differential equations are pretty well studied. In particular, a conservative system with an arbitrary potential energy (so-called *nonlinear oscillator*) will have only one type of stable states, corresponding to its potential minina, with periodic oscillations around each of them.

There may be also periodic trajectories in more complex systems with energy sources and dissipation, but these are probably beyond of what you are asking.

Unfortunately, I am unable to recommend any good books in English. [Here is my list](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3619030/765359) of basic Russian sources (mist existing in translation).

If course, one can also have oscillations in Euler-Lagrange equations without any potential at all - with magnetic field.